# PySpark load files between timestamps

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp, range, wildcard

I have a list of xml files containing a timestamp in the filename. I need to conditionally load those files based on the timestamp value. For this I am using wildcards.

Here the code I am using that is not working:

```
spark.read \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
  .load("/path/file_[1533804409548-1533873609934]*")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this using wildcards as you want to load the files that are within time range. As it's possible to load a dataframe from multiple locations, you can just make a array of file paths that are within the time range and load the paths. Here is the sample code i've tried,

```
target_files = []
st = 123
et = 321
path="<files_base_path>"
for file in os.listdir(path):
    try:
        ts = int(file[5:8])
        if ts >= st and ts <= et:
            target_files.append(path+file)
    except Exception as ex:
        continue
spark.read.parquet(*target_files)
```

Change the constant values based your input. Hopefully it'll help you..